# How to print inline after input

Tags: python, input, layout

I want to receive input by prompt with the following structure:

```
-----------------------------
|                           |
| Digit your name:[]        |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

where [] is the input.

if I do

```
a = int(input('|   |'))
```

it prints:

```
|         | []
```

Or if I do:

```
print('|  {0}  |' .format(input('')))
```

the result is similar.

How can I do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can't make user type in somewhere in your string while using `input`. If you really want, maybe you can use `curses` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out to do it using "end" function and "\r"

The code to do it is:

```
print('|      |' , end='\r|')
```

It was easier that I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible with raw python. While invoking `input()` the command immediatly prints out the string you gave as an argument and shows a prompt for writing. Since the code runs sequentially, its basically impossible to print something after the input line since it will pause the execution before writing anything.

As in @Asocia comment the `curses` module might help you, if this is the kind of behaviour you would like.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already mentioned, it's not possible in raw python. Use curses instead, but this needs a little training period.

I just did some tests with `print(..., end='\r')` and i came up to the following "solution". It does not set the position marker correctly, but it looks like typing inside the square brackets.

May you need to install the python library getkey with `pip3 install --user getkey`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from getkey import getkey, keys

s = ""
print(f'Digit your name: \"{s}\"', end='\r')
while (key := getkey()) != keys.ENTER:
    if key != keys.BACKSPACE and key not in [keys.LEFT, keys.RIGHT, keys.DOWN, keys.UP]:
        s += key
        print(f'Digit your name: "{s}"', end='\r')
    elif key == keys.BACKSPACE:
        s = s[:-1]
        print((len(f"Digit your name: \"{s}\"")+1) * " ", end='\r')
        print(f'Digit your name: \"{s}\"', end='\r')

print("\n" + s)
```

At least this is working on Linux, except of the incorrectly set text marker.